# divide an array into smaller segments

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to take an array and divide the distance between each successive members into smaller segments such that no distance is less than 0.1.
I have tried the following code:

```
arr = [0, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 8.05, 8.25]
n = 10

def create_segments(x, n0, i):
    return np.round(np.linspace(x[i], x[i + 1], n0 + 1), 2)

out = []
for j in range(len(arr)-1):
    xx = create_segments(arr, n, j)
    if any(i < 0.1 for i in np.diff(xx)):
        n = n -1
        out.append(create_segments(arr, n, j))
    else:
        out.append(xx)
result = np.unique(np.concatenate(out))
print('result', result)
```

The output of the code is `[0.   0.4  0.8  1.2  1.6  2.   2.4  2.8  3.2  3.6  4.   4.06 4.11 4.17 4.22 4.28 4.33 4.39 4.44 4.5  4.56 4.62 4.69 4.75 4.81 4.88 4.94 5. 5.38 5.76 6.14 6.52 6.91 7.29 7.67 8.05 8.08 8.11 8.14 8.16 8.19 8.22 8.25]`
for some sections, for example the last section between arr[4]
and arr[5] there are still distances less than 0.1.

I appreciate if anyone make a suggestion to correct the code.

Comment: Can your provide the explicit expected output? (eventually change the number of items in the input or the threshold to make it reasonably small)

Comment: The only condition is that the steps should not be less than 0.1. Since the distances in the original array are not uniform, the number of segments generated would not be the same at each segment. The code, as you can see, operates properly for arr[0] and arr[1], but not for arr[1] and arr[2], for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the values in your array aren't far apart enough for the number of values you are dividing the segment into.  Reducing n by 1 only once doesn't make it small enough, for example between 4.0 and 4.5, you can have at most 5 intermediate values that are 0.1 apart.

Instead of using trial and error, you could directly compute an appropriate number of values for the split:

```
out = []
for j in range(len(arr)-1):
    n = min(10,(arr[j+1]-arr[j])//0.1+1)
    xx = create_segments(arr, n, j)
    out.append(xx)
```

output:

```
result [0.   0.4  0.8  1.2  1.6  2.   2.4  2.8  3.2  3.6  4.   4.1  4.2  4.3
 4.4  4.5  4.6  4.7  4.8  4.9  5.   5.3  5.61 5.92 6.22 6.52 6.83 7.14
 7.44 7.75 8.05 8.15 8.25]
diff [0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1
 0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.3  0.31 0.31 0.3  0.3  0.31 0.31 0.3
 0.31 0.3  0.1  0.1 ]
```

If you still want to use the trial and error approach, you'll need to reset `n` at every segment and reduce it in a while loop:

```
out = []
for j in range(len(arr)-1):
    n = 10
    xx = create_segments(arr, n, j)    
    while any(i < 0.1 for i in np.diff(xx)):
        n = n -1
        xx = create_segments(arr, n, j)
    out.append(xx)
```

Comment: The logic doesn't seem to be entirely correct. For example, it should be possible to divide the last two numbers, 8.05 and 8.25, into the segments 8.05, 8.15, 8.25, with differences of exactly 0.1.

Comment: Thank you Alain. How can I repeat reducing n until the condition satisfies?

Comment: @Payman: I added code to repeat condition.  You will notice that 8.05-->8.25 produces no intermediate value (instead of 8.05, 8.15, 8.25)  This is because linspace with rounding produces value in binary with differences that are a little bit smaller than 0.1  (by 3.6E-16).

Comment: That you Alain. Your direct approach of computing the appropriate value is elegant.